# How to use Html.form in ELM form?

Tags: elm

I want to make an HTML form that actually uses the [form] tag in ELM. None of the example online do this -- they simply put the [input] tags in a [div] instead of a [form]

When I try switching my Elm app to a [form], my [input type=sumbit] tags don't seem to call back to Elm. The submit tries to leave the page and add a "?" to my url.

Any hints on how to do this?

WHY: I want to be a using [form], so I can use the "required" attribute on some [input] fields. This is just one part of my validation, but I like the UI that "required" tag presents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `onSubmit` in `Html.form`.

Here is the example.

```elm
Html.form [ onSubmit Submit ]
  [ input
    [ type' "submit"
    , value "click here to submit"
    ]
    []
  ]
```